# Doubly LinkedList Previous Instance Variable

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So for my java programming class we learned about doubly linked lists and I get the gist of 3 nodes within one object that points to one another. However, in the lab that he's given us, I'm completely lost as to how I would make the nodes within a linked list point towards the previous one. I've seen other programs do the same thing, but yet I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my own code. I've thought about using a "previousNode object" but not sure if that's the correct way to go about it. So my question is how would you create a pointer to the previous node and that previous node to point at the new node? Note: the new node will be added at the end of the list.

Method to add elements in linked list

```
class ElementList
{
 Element       firstNode;
 public ElementList()
{
  this.firstNode = null;
}

 public void addElement( String first, String last, long number )
{
  Element    previousNode, newNode, currentNode;

  newNode = new Element( first, last, number );

  if ( this.firstNode == null)     // Determine if there is a firstNode
  {
     this.firstNode = newNode;      // Store the first node
  }
  else
  {
     currentNode = this.firstNode;  // Assign temporary element to first
     while ( currentNode.nextElement != null )  // Check if this is last element or header
     {
        currentNode = currentNode.nextElement;  // Go to the next element
     }
     currentNode.nextElement = newNode;         // Point last element of list to newNode

  }
}
```

Here's the link of the full source code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18F4nKoRN5kdVcQ7IRWjrCE3hAKGD32BmRxaZTbW7CSc/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the link to the assignment as a whole:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POEAsdNrB3wJPI0ddsbJp2HnUay5pgei/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can avoid the while loop by having a `lastNode` field in your `ElementList` class:

```
class ElementList {
    Element firstNode;
    Element lastNode;

    public ElementList() {
        this.firstNode = null;
        this.lastNode = null;
    }

    public void addElement(String first, String last, long number) {
        Element previousNode, newNode, currentNode;

        newNode = new Element(first, last, number);

        if (this.firstNode == null) // Determine if there is a firstNode
        {
            this.firstNode = newNode;      // Store the first node
            this.lastNode = newNode;       // ... and the last node
        } else {
            this.lastNode.nextElement = newNode;
            this.lastNode = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

It still is a singly-linked list for the moment, but you can add a `previousElement` field in your `Element` class, and change the `addElement` method slightly:

```
    public void addElement(String first, String last, long number) {
        Element previousNode, newNode, currentNode;

        newNode = new Element(first, last, number);

        if (this.firstNode == null) // Determine if there is a firstNode
        {
            this.firstNode = newNode;      // Store the first node
            this.lastNode = newNode;       // ... and the last node
        } else {
            this.lastNode.nextElement = newNode;
            newNode.previousElement = this.lastNode;
            this.lastNode = newNode;
        }
    }
```

Now you may want to write a method that removes a node:

```
public void removeElement(Element node) {
    if (node.nextElement == null) {
        // node is the last node
        this.lastNode = node.previousElement;
        if (this.lastNode != null) {
            this.lastNode.nextElement = null;
        }
    } else {
        node.nextElement.previousElement = node.previousElement;
    }
    if (node.previousElement == null) {
        // node is the first node
        this.firstNode = node.nextElement;
        if (this.firstNode != null) {
            this.firstNode.previousElement = null;
        }
    } else {
        node.previousElement.nextElement = node.nextElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely helps a lot!